# Application Not Authorized to Use CAS

Tags: cas

I have installed CAS6.4 and CAS Management .
I am able to access https://CNNAME/cas/login & it successfully login .
I could also Login to https://hostanme/cas-management/ and it redirect back to cas management.

I have added service URL in cas management  as below :

^(http|https)://CNNAME*/**

http*://**hostname2*/**

But when i access these URL, i get error as

Application Not Authorized to Use CAS
The application you attempted to authenticate to is not authorized to use CAS. This usually indicates that the application is not registered with CAS, or its authorization policy defined in its registration record prevents it from leveraging CAS functionality, or it's malformed and unrecognized by CAS. Contact your CAS administrator to learn how you might register and integrate your application with CAS.

In the logs i get error as :

2021-03-01 07:15:39,111 WARN [org.apereo.cas.services.RegisteredServiceAccessStrategyUtils] - <Unauthorized Service Access. Service [https://hostanme/callback] is not found in service registry.>

I have been struggling to get this solved for for days, could someone please help me with this.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did u find a solution?